# Python facebook SDK permission error for post to page

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have created a facebook page and I am trying to post on page wall using below code. It is written in python and using facebook SDK.

```
def main():
  cfg = {
    "page_id"      : "PAGE_ID",  # Step 1
    "access_token" : "USER_ACCESS_TOKEN"   # Step 3
    }

  graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cfg['access_token'])
  id = graph.get_object('me')['id']
  print(graph.get_permissions(user_id=id))
  resp = graph.get_object('me/accounts')

  page_access_token = None
  for page in resp['data']:
      if page['id'] == cfg['page_id']:
          page_access_token = page['access_token']
  api = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)

  msg = "Hello, world!"
  print(api.get_permissions(user_id=id))
  print(api.put_wall_post(msg))
```

It is giving below output with error:

```
{'user_posts', 'publish_actions', 'public_profile', 'pages_manage_cta', 'manage_pages'}
{'user_posts', 'publish_actions', 'public_profile', 'pages_manage_cta', 'manage_pages'}
    print(api.put_wall_post(msg))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\facebook_sdk-3.0.0a0-py3.4.egg\facebook\__init__.py", line 188, in put_wall_post
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\facebook_sdk-3.0.0a0-py3.4.egg\facebook\__init__.py", line 169, in put_object
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\facebook_sdk-3.0.0a0-py3.4.egg\facebook\__init__.py", line 298, in request
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

I dont understand what I did wrong? I gave permission to user correctly. I checked other duplicate questions but their solutions are not working with current facebookSDK. Can someone please help me?

Comment: The user need to grant the app publish_pages to publish on pages

Comment: Thank you so much, I was struggling for 6 hours to achieve this.

Comment: Please post it as answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

For the page you to post, go to About  tab on page and get the Page ID at the bottom. Take a note or save it. Then,

- First create an app on facebook developer console:
  https://developers.facebook.com/apps. Providing display name and email, click Create App ID.

  - Goto Settings > Basic> Select Category(Apps for pages) > Save changes.
  - Goto App Review > Make ‘AppName’ Public at top > Toggle to yes and then Confirm. This will make the app public.
  - Goto Dashboard again and take note of App ID and App Secret (Click Show next to it, it will ask for fb password).

Now generate access token:

- Goto https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. In the Application dropdown > Select the app created earlier > From Get Token > Get User Access Token> From select Permissions > check manage_pages, publish_actions, publish_pages > Get Access Token.
- Click continue as user(Username), the token will be generated.
- Token that appears in the "Access Token" field is your short-lived access token. Save this token as this token will be required to generate the long-lived token.

This is a short-lived token will expire within two hours. Save the token. Install facebook sdk:

```
pip install facebook-sdk
```

Use the following code:

```
import facebook

def main():
  # Fill in the values noted in previous steps here
  cfg = {
  "page_id"      : "value of the page id",  # Step 1
  "access_token" : "token you generated"   # Step 3
  }

api = get_api(cfg)
msg = "Hello, world!"
status = api.put_wall_post(msg)

def get_api(cfg):
  graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cfg['access_token'])
  # Get page token to post as the page. You can skip 
  # the following if you want to post as yourself. 
  resp = graph.get_object('me/accounts')
  page_access_token = None
  for page in resp['data']:
     if page['id'] == cfg['page_id']:
     page_access_token = page['access_token']
     graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
     return graph

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Or simply you can use the following:

```
import facebook
def main():
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='your_user_access_token', version='2.8')
    #if version 2.8 show error use 2.6
    attachment =  {
        'name': 'Link name'
        'link': 'https://www.example.com/',
        'caption': 'Check out this example',
        'description': 'This is a longer description of the attachment',
        'picture': 'https://www.example.com/thumbnail.jpg'
    }

    graph.put_wall_post(message='Check this out...', attachment=attachment, profile_id='your_page_id')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Remember the token will expire within 2 hours. In that case you can generate a long lived token or permanent token.

Comment: I used the solution provided by WizKid in the comments. I was missing publish_pages permission. That resolved the issue.